# How to remove class 'open' from nav in CoreUI react theme?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

When I go browser then 'Active session' menu is by default open, I want to it's open when I click on 'Active session' menu.
Found in the debugging, I need to remove 'open' class on default. 
Please see my below code and screenshot and please suggest me, Thanks.
I'm using below code for showing menu.

DefaultLayout.js:

```
import navigation from '../../_nav';

render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader fixed>
          <Suspense  fallback={this.loading()}>
            <DefaultHeader onLogout={e=>this.signOut(e)}/>
          </Suspense>
        </AppHeader>
        <div className="app-body">
          <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <Suspense>
            <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} router={router}/>
            </Suspense>
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
          </AppSidebar>
</div>
 </div>
 );
  }
```

_nav.js is :-

```
export default {
  items: [
    {
      name: 'Dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      icon: 'icon-speedometer',
     /* badge: {
        variant: 'info',
        text: 'NEW',
      },*/
    },
      {
          name: 'Players',
          url: '/player',
          icon: 'icon-puzzle',
      },
      {
          name: 'Activity',
          url: '/activity',
          icon: 'icon-drop',
      },
      {
          name: 'Angle Alerts',
          url: '/angle',
          icon: 'icon-cursor',
      },
      {
          name: 'Session',
          url: '/session',
          icon: 'icon-star',
      },
      {
          name: 'Active Session',
          url: '/',
          icon: 'icon-star',
          attributes: {rel: "noopener" },
          children: [
              {
                  name: 'Group',
                  url: '/active/group',
                  /*icon: 'icon-puzzle',*/
              },
              {
                  name: 'Individual',
                  url: '/active/individual'
              }
        ]
      },
 ],
};
```

and my result is :

[image]

```
var AppSidebarNav2 = function (_Component) {
  _inherits(AppSidebarNav2, _Component);

  function AppSidebarNav2(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, AppSidebarNav2);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Component.call(this, props));

    _this.handleClick = _this.handleClick.bind(_this);
    _this.activeRoute = _this.activeRoute.bind(_this);
    _this.hideMobile = _this.hideMobile.bind(_this);
    return _this;
  }

  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.handleClick = function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
  };

  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.activeRoute = function activeRoute(routeName, props) {
    return props.location.pathname.indexOf(routeName) > -1 ? 'nav-item nav-dropdown open' : 'nav-item nav-dropdown';
  };

  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.hideMobile = function hideMobile() {
    if (document.body.classList.contains('sidebar-show')) {
      document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-show');
    }
  };

  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.getAttribs = function getAttribs(attributes) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributes || {}));
  };

  // nav list


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navList = function navList(items) {
    var _this2 = this;

    return items.map(function (item, index) {
      return _this2.navType(item, index);
    });
  };

  // nav type


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navType = function navType(item, idx) {
    return item.title ? this.navTitle(item, idx) : item.divider ? this.navDivider(item, idx) : item.label ? this.navLabel(item, idx) : item.children ? this.navDropdown(item, idx) : this.navItem(item, idx);
  };

  // nav list section title


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navTitle = function navTitle(title, key) {
    var classes = classNames('nav-title', title.class, title.className);
    return React.createElement(
      'li',
      { key: key, className: classes },
      this.navWrapper(title),
      ' '
    );
  };

  // simple wrapper for nav-title item


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navWrapper = function navWrapper(item) {
    return item.wrapper && item.wrapper.element ? React.createElement(item.wrapper.element, item.wrapper.attributes, item.name) : item.name;
  };

  // nav list divider


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navDivider = function navDivider(divider, key) {
    var classes = classNames('divider', divider.class, divider.className);
    return React.createElement('li', { key: key, className: classes });
  };

  // nav label with nav link


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navLabel = function navLabel(item, key) {
    var classes = {
      item: classNames('hidden-cn', item.class),
      link: classNames('nav-label', item.class ? item.class : ''),
      icon: classNames('nav-icon', !item.icon ? 'fa fa-circle' : item.icon, item.label.variant ? 'text-' + item.label.variant : '', item.label.class ? item.label.class : '')
    };
    return this.navLink(item, key, classes);
  };

  // nav dropdown


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navDropdown = function navDropdown(item, key) {
    var classIcon = classNames('nav-icon', item.icon);
    var attributes = this.getAttribs(item.attributes);
    var classes = classNames('nav-link', 'nav-dropdown-toggle', item.class, attributes.class, attributes.className);
    delete attributes.class;
    delete attributes.className;
    var itemAttr = this.getAttribs(item.itemAttr);
    var liClasses = classNames(this.activeRoute(item.url, this.props), itemAttr.class, itemAttr.className);
    delete itemAttr.class;
    delete itemAttr.className;
    return React.createElement(
      'li',
      _extends({ key: key, className: liClasses }, itemAttr),
      React.createElement(
        'a',
        _extends({ className: classes, href: '#', onClick: this.handleClick }, attributes),
        React.createElement('i', { className: classIcon }),
        item.name,
        this.navBadge(item.badge)
      ),
      React.createElement(
        'ul',
        { className: 'nav-dropdown-items' },
        this.navList(item.children)
      )
    );
  };

  // nav item with nav link


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navItem = function navItem(item, key) {
    var classes = {
      item: classNames(item.class),
      link: classNames('nav-link', item.variant ? 'nav-link-' + item.variant : ''),
      icon: classNames('nav-icon', item.icon)
    };
    return this.navLink(item, key, classes);
  };

  // nav link


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navLink = function navLink(item, key, classes) {
    var url = item.url || '';
    var itemIcon = React.createElement('i', { className: classes.icon });
    var itemBadge = this.navBadge(item.badge);
    var attributes = this.getAttribs(item.attributes);
    classes.link = classNames(classes.link, attributes.class, attributes.className);
    delete attributes.class;
    delete attributes.className;
    var itemAttr = this.getAttribs(item.itemAttr);
    classes.item = classNames(classes.item, itemAttr.class, itemAttr.className);
    delete itemAttr.class;
    delete itemAttr.className;
    var NavLink = this.props.router.NavLink || RsNavLink;
    return React.createElement(
      NavItem,
      _extends({ key: key, className: classes.item }, itemAttr),
      attributes.disabled ? React.createElement(
        RsNavLink,
        _extends({ href: '', className: classes.link }, attributes),
        itemIcon,
        item.name,
        itemBadge
      ) : this.isExternal(url, this.props) || NavLink === RsNavLink ? React.createElement(
        RsNavLink,
        _extends({ href: url, className: classes.link, active: true }, attributes),
        itemIcon,
        item.name,
        itemBadge
      ) : React.createElement(
        NavLink,
        _extends({ to: url, className: classes.link, activeClassName: 'active', onClick: this.hideMobile }, attributes),
        itemIcon,
        item.name,
        itemBadge
      )
    );
  };

  // badge addon to NavItem


  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.navBadge = function navBadge(badge) {
    if (badge) {
      var classes = classNames(badge.class, badge.className);
      return React.createElement(
        Badge,
        { className: classes, color: badge.variant },
        badge.text
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.isExternal = function isExternal(url, props) {
    var linkType = typeof url === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(url);
    var link = linkType === 'string' ? url : linkType === 'object' && url.pathname ? url.pathname : linkType === 'function' && typeof url(props.location) === 'string' ? url(props.location) : linkType === 'function' && _typeof(url(props.location)) === 'object' ? url(props.location).pathname : '';
    return link.substring(0, 4) === 'http';
  };

  AppSidebarNav2.prototype.render = function render() {
    var _props = this.props,
        className = _props.className,
        children = _props.children,
        navConfig = _props.navConfig,
        attributes = _objectWithoutProperties(_props, ['className', 'children', 'navConfig']);

    delete attributes.isOpen;
    delete attributes.staticContext;
    delete attributes.Tag;
    delete attributes.router;

    var navClasses = classNames(className, 'sidebar-nav');

    // ToDo: find better rtl fix
    var isRtl = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).direction === 'rtl';

    // sidebar-nav root
    return React.createElement(
      PerfectScrollbar,
      _extends({ className: navClasses }, attributes, { options: { suppressScrollX: !isRtl } }),
      React.createElement(
        Nav,
        null,
        children || this.navList(navConfig.items)
      )
    );
  };

  return AppSidebarNav2;
}(Component);
```

Comment: need AppSidebarNav component or function code here

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi Edited, please check above.

Comment: Hmm, not a component you own. Does anything in [SideBarNav.md](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react/blob/master/src/SidebarNav.md) help? Looks like you can specify the (optional) class, it doesn't look like your `items` has one specified, so maybe it is coming from somewhere else. This [issue](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template/issues/148) may have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. change this code:

   ```
   AppSidebarNav2.prototype.activeRoute = function activeRoute(routeName, props) {
       return props.location.pathname.indexOf(routeName) > -1 ? 'nav-item nav-dropdown open' : 'nav-item nav-dropdown';
     };
   ```

   to :

   ```
   AppSidebarNav2.prototype.activeRoute = function activeRoute(routeName, props) {
       return (routeName !== '/' && props.location.pathname.indexOf(routeName) > -1) ? 'nav-item nav-dropdown open' : 'nav-item nav-dropdown';
     };
   ```
2. or change this:

   ```
   {
         name: 'Active Session',
         url: '/',
         icon: 'icon-star',
         attributes: {rel: "noopener" },
         children: [
             {
                 name: 'Group',
                 url: '/active/group',
                 /*icon: 'icon-puzzle',*/
             },
             {
                 name: 'Individual',
                 url: '/active/individual'
             }
       ]
     },
   ```

   to:

   ```
   {
         name: 'Active Session',
         url: '/ActiveSession', // <- change this value from '/' to any valuable string you want except '/'
         icon: 'icon-star',
         attributes: {rel: "noopener" },
         children: [
             {
                 name: 'Group',
                 url: '/active/group',
                 /*icon: 'icon-puzzle',*/
             },
             {
                 name: 'Individual',
                 url: '/active/individual'
             }
       ]
     },
   ```

Comment: First option need to stop nodejs and restart it and run your project again (npm start) but recommended way is 2